# Firebase realtime database list of values retrieved

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Dear Friends,

I am accessing data from a Firebase database, however I am unable to get a list of my data.

I am getting the following exception:

```
E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.sg.rapid.Models.AlaramData`
```

here is my code:

```
 mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                AlaramData  usersList =  dataSnapshot.getValue(AlaramData.class);
                String name = usersList.getStatus();
                childList.add(usersList);
                // here you can access to name property like university.name
            }

            Log.d("", "Value is: " + childList);
            //Create a List of Section DataModel implements Section

            sections.add(new SectionHeader(childList, "2018", 1));
            adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you indicate the line where this error happens? Is it in the line `AlaramData  usersList =  dataSnapshot.getValue(AlaramData.class);`?

Comment: correct, this is the line I am getting error...

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error message, we can understand that the method is returning an ArrayList of your elements, then I noticed you used the wrong variable there.

It should be using postSnapshot instead of dataSnapshot. Try this:

```
AlaramData usersList = postSnapshot.getValue(AlaramData.class);
```

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.sg.rapid.Models.AlaramData,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by changing the json structure in firebase database.
[image]

the code as follows:

// Read from the database

```
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override


        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            Log.d("", "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            sections.clear();



             childList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                AlaramData    alaramData =  postSnapshot.getValue(AlaramData.class);
               int x = 0;
                // here you can access to name property like university.name
                childList.add(alaramData);
            }


            Log.d("", "Value is: " + childList);
            //Create a List of Section DataModel implements Section

            sections.add(new SectionHeader(childList, "2018", 1));
            adapterRecycler.notifyDataChanged(sections);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```